# Custom MIB Textual Representation

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I am an snmp beginner and have created a custom MIB and included it in snmpd.conf via pass persist.
`pass_persist .1.3.6.1.4.1.56947.1.1 /usr/bin/env python3 -u my_script.py`

While I can successfully query the data, the returned data is a mix between the OIDs and the textual representation of OIDs.

Something like
`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.56947.1.1.1`

If I query, for example the UCD MIB (.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021)
I get the full textual representation, like `UCD-SNMP-MIB::memIndex.0` which corresponds to `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.1`

As far as I know the UCD Mibs have been merged into net-snmp itself and may work differently than my own MIB.

My MIB (ommited some parts for brevity)

```
MY-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
IMPORTS
  MODULE-IDENTITY, enterprises, Integer32
  FROM SNMPv2-SMI

myMIB MODULE-IDENTITY
 -- identify stuff
 ::= { enterprises 56947 }

product1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { myMIB 1 }
product1Data OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { product1 1 }
objectCount OBJECT-TYPE
  SYNTAX      Integer32
  MAX-ACCESS  read-only
  STATUS      current
  DESCRIPTION "test"
  ::= { product1Data 1 }

END
```

But is this behavior by design or am I missing something?

My excpectation/wish would be to receive something like `MY-MIB::objectCount`

Comment: Where did you put your MIB document? If not loaded by NET-SNMP commands, you see things like `SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.56947.1.1.1`

Comment: I put it into `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` where I found all the other MIBS.
Does the file name have to correspond to the name at `DEFINITIONS` in the file?

Comment: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Loading_your_own_MIBs

Comment: I mixed up agent and manager and thought the tools like `snmpwalk` and `snmptranslate` use the config `/etc/snmp/snmp**d**.conf` but they use `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`.
In this config (on the manager machine) I added the line `mibs +MY-MIB` and it worked. Also add your mib file to your manager/client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed up agent and manager and thought the tools like `snmpwalk` and `snmptranslate` use the config `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` (note the **d** at the end) but they use `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`.
I added line
`mibs +MY-MIB`
in `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` (on the manager machine) and it worked.

Also add your mib file to your manager/client (I added mine to `/usr/share/snmp/mibs`)